# Using this code to export mysql table to csv - but I need syntax for MAC not PC

Tags: mysql, export-to-csv

Code for windows environment is below:

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/documents/products.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM products
```

Just need the 2nd line for MAC environment - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to put your `FROM` clause before `INTO OUTFILE`.

Second, be sure that the directory specified in `OUTFILE` has the ability for MySQL to write to it (in your case `/documents`). You'll have a much easier time writing to `/tmp` (MySQL already has permissions to write by default) than trying to change permissions on another directory to accept writes form your MySQL database.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM products 
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/products.csv' 
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
         ENCLOSED BY '"' 
         ESCAPED BY '\\' 
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: Mac newbie here - is there a way to see what folders will accept files?

Comment: @Gricks on the command line type `ls -al`. That will list the permissions of all of the files/directories under the current working directory on the command line. What you're looking for is `777` permissions on a directory, or more specifically `drwxrwxrwx` (or with a sticky bit like `/tmp`, `drwxrwxrwt`) on the directory you want to write your `OUTFILE` to.

Comment: thanks for your help - I went into terminal and changed the permissions - still not working    18:03:34 Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'gricks'@'%' (using password: YES) 0.065 sec